# perform action A for each B in each C ... if D in tree

Tags: c#, abstract-class, func

I'm trying to create an abstract class that performs given tasks on specific elements. Two examples that share logic:

**Example A**

```
foreach (DraftDocument draft in drafts)
    foreach (Sheet sheet in draft.Sheets)
        foreach (Symbol symbol in sheet.Symbols)
            if(conditions) do action
```

**Example B**

```
foreach (DraftDocument draft in drafts)
    foreach (Sheet sheet in draft.Sheets)
        foreach (View view in sheet.Views)
            if(conditions) do action
```

I would like to reuse the `foreach` logic, and create a function that takes both a condition method and an action method, and performs it on a given dataset (in this case, a list of DraftDocuments).

What would be a good way to create such? I read something about the Func delegate, but I'm not sure how to implement this correctly.

Comment: do you know `Func<bool>` and `Action`? They are designed exactly for those purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
public class DocumentVisitor
{
   private readonly IEnumerable<DraftDocument> _drafts;

   private void Visit(Action<Sheet> visitor)
   {
       foreach(DraftDocument draft in _drafts)
           foreach(Sheet sheet in draft.Sheets)
               visitor(sheet);
   }

   public DocumentVisitor(IEnumerable<DraftDocument> drafts) => _drafts = drafts;

   public void VisitSymbols(Action<Symbol> visitor) =>
       Visit(sheet =>
       {
           foreach(Symbol symbol in sheet.Symbols)
               visitor(symbol);
       });

   public void VisitViews(Action<View> visitor) =>
       Visit(sheet=>
       {
           foreach(View view in sheet.Views)
               visitor(view);
       });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Creating an extension method to encapsulate the predicate and action logic and making use of `SelectMany` is, IMHO, enough:

```
public static void DoActionIf<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Predicate<TSource> predicate,
    Action<TSource> action)
{
    foreach (var s in source)
    {
        if (predicate(s))
            action(s);
    }
}
```

And you'd use it like:

```
drafts.SelectMany(draft => draft.Sheets)
      .SelectMany(sheet => sheet.Symbols)
      .DoActionIf(symbol => symbol != null, 
                  symbol => Console.WriteLine(sy));
```